# Mapping two columns with the same name in nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hibernate-mapping

I've come across a case, we're I've a column mapped twice (un-beknown to us..), and now updates are throwing the "Parameter +1 doesn't exist error".

Is there any suitable way we can achieve the following mapping?

(Please note, this is an inherited database...)

```
        References(x => x.Matter).Columns(new[] { "c_client", "c_matter" }).NotFound.Ignore();
        References(x => x.Client).Column("c_client");
```

Comment: does the Client field need to be updateable in the entity?

Comment: I don't think they do - if you have a better alternative to @diago, I'd love to hear it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an invalid mapping. You can't use the same column twice.

My suggestion is that you map `c_matter` and `c_client` as scalar properties and use queries to retrieve the corresponding matters and clients.

Comment: That is the answer I should have thought of!

Comment: Actually - on that thought, any suggestions on how I could get a IRepository down to my entity layer?

Comment: The least obtrusive is passing it. `theEntity.GetMatter(repository)`

Comment: Good idea..! I took it out of there completely, and kept anything to do with Clients into a client Services class - as it required the extra query to get it anyway.

I also added DTO for times when it is required to be returned from the DTO, and thus not really accessed via the main object anyway.. (Just took a day of refractoring/fixing tests..)

Answer (score 3):

An option for you could be to mark the Client column as read only.

```
References(x => x.Matter).Columns(new[] { "c_client", "c_matter" }).NotFound.Ignore();
References(x => x.Client).Column("c_client").ReadOnly();
```

This should make it so NHiberante does not try to update it

Comment: Thanks for this - I'll keep it it mind for the future - however, I'll stick with all refreactoring, and DTO's (as they'd have happened anyway!) +1